# How to stop AJAX update taking place in one update panel from another update panel?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, ajax

We have two update panels on our webpage. Now first update panel is having button cancel. While second update panel is having a file upload control.

Now if the user uploads a file that is going to upload in about 2 mins, and in between, say after 30 seconds the user clicks the cancel button, the upload taking place in update panel 2 should stop.

How do we achieve this ?

Comment: That's a good question.  It seems that a bunch of 3rd party controls that can be purchased have this ability so it is possible.  The question is how involved the process of making this happen is. By nature when 2 simultaneous requests occur, only the latest is processed. Have you just tried pressing a cancel button that posts backs to the server but does nothing more to see if it cancels the request?  http://disturbedbuddha.wordpress.com/2007/12/12/handling-multiple-asynchronous-postbacks/

Answer (score 0):

use the keyword mode="conditional" in the update panel tag.. hope this solves..

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'conditional mode' in update mode. Also if the button is outside update panel you can use an update panel trigger to refresh the other update panel.
http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2007/05/16/112526.aspx